# What are the operators <,> supposed to do with one or both objects being set to 'Nothing'?

Tags: .net, vb.net, comparison, icomparable

Using 2 objects of the same type, I'm trying to implement `<` and `>`, but I can't seem to find any authoritative source on what to do with either or both being `Nothing`. In other words what the accepted practice or MSDN suggestions are.

Example code:

```
Private Shared _accessors As IEnumerable(Of Func(Of CmykColor, Decimal))
Public Shared Operator >(ByVal color1 As CmykColor, ByVal color2 As CmykColor) As Boolean
            //' A null object is always less than a non-null object
            If color1 Is Nothing OrElse color2 Is Nothing Then Return False
            Dim foundGreater As Boolean
            For Each prop In _accessors
                If prop(color1) < prop(color2) Then Return False
                If foundGreater = False AndAlso prop(color1) > prop(color2) Then foundGreater = True
            Next
            Return foundGreater
        End Operator
```

Accessors is my canonical method for centralizing an enumeration of the properties (all are decimal)

return false for both if either is `Nothing`?

I found a comment, but can't seem to verify or validate it that

> A null object is always less than a non-null object

How do I handle `Nothing`?

Comment: **It really just depends on your class design and what the operators mean semantically.** There's no "best practice" or rule to follow here, other than you should generally refrain from overloading the `<` and `>` operators in the first place unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: Personally I'd expect a type representing a colour to be a value type, so this wouldn't arise.

Comment: IMO you should never use < > on anything that could be null.  I would do somthing like `.compareTo()` where  `prop(color1).CompareTo(prop(color2))` this returns either -1,0, or 1. Also, I noticed you never set foundGreater to false.

Comment: @Cody - well since I didn't find any guidelines specific to `<` or `>` in the design guidelines, I figured the guidelines to `!=` and `==` were the next best thing.
@Doug - Thanks for the catch, checking the code against it.

Comment: True, but if you want to compare complex datatypes unless you overload the operators > <; you may return unexpected results with empty or null objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i was looking for:

> By definition, any object compares
>   greater than (or follows) null, and
>   two null references compare equal to
>   each other.

From Msdn documentation on [IComparable.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx)

I don't see any reasoning or drawbacks to following compareTo on this as a general rule.
Then, for specific usages or context check if throwing an exception makes more sense.

Comment: This is a very strange "definition". A null should never be equal to a null, because a null value is undefined. Two things that are undefined can't be equal to each other, because we don't know what they are.

Answer (score 1):

Considering this an **exceptional** case, you could throw an exception.

You can also follow what framework does and return `False`.

### Example:

```
Dim result As Boolean = (New DateTime() > New DateTime()) ' result is False
```

**Edit**

And to be consistent, language itself returns `False` with following code:

```
Dim result As Boolean = (Nothing > Nothing) ' result is False
```

Also, theoretically, if both are `Nothing`, both are equal. And no one is greater than or less than the other one.

For example,

```
1 > 1  ' False
1 < 1  ' False
1 == 1 ' True
```

Comment: I'm aware I have a lot of I could options, this being one of them. However, I'm looking for a standard practice or generality that may apply to more than my tiny use case for future knowledge going forward in this and more cases to come. Places I'm not aware of that doing it other ways are likely to cause compatibility issues or unexpected results.

Comment: Nothing will NEVER be equal to Nothing since Nothing is NULL and NULL is not a value. NULL == NULL will always be false. XYZ == NULL can be true or false however.

Comment: Would this solution be subject to the sorting algorithm flaw found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/01/20/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-one.aspx  Where > < and = all return false if either or both are nothing?